# Android manifest write storage permission

Tags: android, angular, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-13

i have this uses permission on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
```

if i want to delete permission write external storage..and i build my apps again. this permission is come back again. the purpose i want to delete it because on Android 13, somehow google change it to another code.

i got info from here [source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)

any idea how to remove that write external storage? or how to deal with it on Android 13?

thanks

i already try to delete that permission on my androidmanifest but it come back again after i rebuild my apps.

Comment: Permissions are transitive across your dependencies.  If they require something, your app requires it.  Sounds like some library you're dependent on uses WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.  I'd check for that, and remove that dependency if you can.

Comment: but for android 13, google change it. i need that write external storage to handle access camera. at the moment that permission not asking in my app because the device has android 13. how to handle it in android 13 to access storage and camera?

Comment: You dont have to remove it. You dont have to deal with it. It does not harm. It does nothing.

Comment: On Android 13+ you have write permission in public dirs on external storage by default.

Comment: hi @blackapps can you give more specific where i should write that permission? you said public dirs? where is it actually? thanks

Comment: `where i should write that permission? you said public dirs` ??? You should not write permissions in directories. You should create and write files in public directories on external storage.

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment_DIRECTORY_DCIM)`.